# Need to add touch events?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, touch

So I'm having a little trouble adding touch events so I can get this page slider to work. It works with the scroll mouse and keys but not on mobile touch. See code in codepen link....

```
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="EyLWKg" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="WispProxy" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Gray & White - Skewed Slider with Scrolling" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/WispProxy/pen/EyLWKg/">Gray & White - Skewed Slider with Scrolling</a> by Victor Belozyorov (<a href="https://codepen.io/WispProxy">@WispProxy</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have JQuery
2. Add this to your JS file

   ```
   $('.codepen a').on('click touch',function(){ 
     $('.codepen a').click(); 
    });
   ```